# Рандомное значение с float

Tags: c#

Мне нужно получить `float` как это происходит с int в `random.Next()`

`x` и `width`, являются `float`

Я хотел бы получить всё таки без усечения значение.

```
float coordX = random.Next((int)x,(int)(x + width));
```

Если я правильно понял, то другие методы класса рандом с вещественными работают от 0.0 до 1.0 только.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именно нужно получить и в чем проблема. Чем не устраивает код, который в вопросе?

Comment: @Эникейщик `x` и `width`, являются `float`, если я привожу их к `(int)` значение усекается, соответственно я могу получить не верное значение в итоге в `coordX`. Которое в дальнейшем будет приводить к ошибке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берите nextdouble, умножайте на нужный диапазон и смещайте на нужный оффсет:

```
coordX  = (random.NextDouble() * width) + x
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо большое!